# Returning an invalid reference

Tags: c++

Sometimes when I'm programming in C++ I wish there was an `undefined` value for every variable something like Javascript!.
For example when I'm returning a value for out-of-bounds element of an array, it was useful to return an `undefined` instead of throwing an exception, or:

```
template <typename T, int SIZE>
class MyArray
{
  T arr[SIZE];
  static T badref;
public:
  T &operator[](int i)
  {
    if (i >=0 && i < SIZE)
      return arr[i];
    else
      throw std::string("OUT-OF-BOUNDS"); // or: return badref; !!
  }
};
```

Another dirty(In my opinion) option is returning a reference of a pre-defind variable as a bad-reference variable. I know we can not assign `null` or something like that to a reference variable.

Is there an another well formed pattern to return a reference where caller has the ability to find out the returned value is not valid?

**EDIT:** I'm not mean a `pointer`

Comment: Yes, it's called a pointer. Alternatively, `boost::optional`.

Comment: At least make your badref object static, then it won't take up space in every MyArray you create. But I agree, it's ugly. In generic code like that I would rather throw an exception

Comment: BTW there's `std::array` that supports access with bounds checking using `arr.at(i)` and without bounds checking using `arr[i]`. `.at()` throws an exception on out-of-bounds.

Comment: boost::optional is the way to go here, but an array is probably not a good use-case. In C# nullables are available as a language construct intended to map cleanly to NULL-able columns in databases.

Comment: @Kos: It's just an example to describe my question. I know about `std::array`. But my question is a general issue.

Comment: If you can't compare object pointers (e.g. to compare to static `badref`), another option is to have a private member variable that basically indicates it's bad...

Comment: @MasoudM.: Amusingly, I am *very glad* that not everything is nullable. When nullability is part of the type system, a whole class of error can be checked by the compiler :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use boost::optional as @chris mentioned in his comment. It comes as a part of Boost libary. See [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) for more details.

Modified `MyArray` class:

```
template <typename T, int SIZE>
class MyArray
{
  T arr[SIZE];
public:
  optional<T&> operator[](int i)
  {
    if (i >=0 && i < SIZE)
      return optional<T&>(arr[i]);
    else
      return optional<T&>();
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
MyArray<int>() array;
// fill array with data

optional<int&> result = array[0];
if (result) {
    // item was found
} else {
    // index out of bounds
}
```

Comment: @DenisErmolin I personally prefer boost::optional, since it explicitly states that the return value of operator[] might be undefined and you should check for this condition.

Comment: @MasoudM. I edited my answer and added link for documentation. You can find out more about Boost here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/index.html

Comment: @MiroslavBajtoš: beware, you don't want `boost::optional<T>&` (reference to optional T) you want `boost::optional<T&>` (optional reference to T). As it is, your code exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

> I wish there was an undefined value for every variable something like Javascript!

You only have an "undefined" value for pointers (nullptr). A reference is (by definition) something pointing to a *valid* instance.

To return a reference to a static object, you should separate between const and non-const values of your operator:

```
template <typename T, int SIZE>
class MyArray
{
  T arr[SIZE];
  static T badref;
public:
  T &operator[](int i)
  {
    if (i >=0 && i < SIZE)
      return arr[i];
    else
      // returning ref here would allow clients to write:
      // MyArray<int> a;
      // a[-1] = 5; // valid if you return a non-const reference
      throw std::string("OUT-OF-BOUNDS");
  }
  const T &operator[](int i) const
  {
    if (i >=0 && i < SIZE)
      return arr[i];
    else {
      // MyArray<int> a;
      // a[-1] = 5; // will not compile (cannot assign to const)
      static const T invalid = T();
      return invalid;
    }
  }
```

};

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you think of, your solution needs to fit into the type system. So your function signature must explicitly say (this way or another) that the result may be T, but it may be something else too.

Common ways for that are:

- Instead of returning a value, return a status code and output the value via an "out" parameter (a pointer or reference):

  ```
  bool tryGet(int i, T& result);
  ```
- Return a tuple (status, value) like:

  ```
  std::tuple<bool, T> get(int i)
  ```

  *(If couldn't get, consider the second tuple element irrelevant - requires T to have a default constructor)*
- Use `boost::variant` (flexible, but requires boost)
- Use `boost::optional` (simpler version of the above, when you only need "either T or nothing")

Answer (score 0):

The main goal of references is to avoid invalid (NULL) values while allowing functions to modify their arguments and keep from copying data.  If you need a NULL value, use a pointer.