# How to return a reference to an object (from an unordered_map), when the key may not exist?

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I have an Object:

```
class Object{
public:
Object(std::vector<int>stuff){

    }
}
```

Each of these objects is only accessible from a class Foo:

```
class Foo{
public:
std::unordered_map<int,Object> _objects;

bool getObjectForId(const int& objectId,Object& rep){
     bool found = false;
     std::unordered_map<int, Object>::const_iterator got = _objects.find(objectId);
     if(got != _objects.end()){
        found = true;
        rep = _objects[objectId];
     }
     return found;
}
```

In some other class I will try to get a reference to an object by doing:

```
class Other{
private:
   Foo myFoo;
public:

   void changeSomeObjectProperty(const int& objectId){
       Object rep;  
       bool gotIt = myFoo.getObjectForId(objectId,rep);

       //Then I will do some stuff with the rep, if gotIt is true
   }
}
```

Does this pattern make sense ? I do not want a copy of the object. I want a reference to the object, but I am trying to avoid using pointers...

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416488/returning-an-invalid-reference

Comment: You could return a `std::pair` with the boolean value in `first` and `second` being an iterator to the found value, or `end` if not found. This pattern is already use by e.g. [`std::unordered_map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Is the way I am returning it now wrong ? I simply do not use the object reference if the value of the returned bool is false ?

Comment: @deepmax I'm trying to avoid using pointers, and don't want to use boost or any other framework... I'm just trying to understand how to do this with plain C++

Comment: It's not wrong. There is no right or wrong here, it's just a matter of personal style. which unfortunately makes this question opinion-based. As long as it's well-documented, all working ways are right.

Comment: One problem with such pattern is that you need a default constructor for `Object`, which may not make sense... Using `optional` or a pointer avoid this. You can easily simulate your own "optional" using a pair of `bool`/`iterator` encapsulated in a proxy class.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so in the function changeSomeObjectProperty, rep will refer to the reference ? It won't be a copy ?

Comment: @Holt Can you explain how I can use optional to do this ?

Comment: Read the first comment.

Comment: Does the concept of iterators fall into the definition of "plain C++"? Then you probably need to create iterator subclass and return it: `MyIterator getObjectForId(const int objectId)` and `MyIterator end()`.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use a pointer here - it fits perfectly. A function that returns a pointer to me indicates the possibility that it could be `nullptr`, a reference always indicates the presence of an item. With the former a simple check can be applied at the call-site and with the latter, the implication is that no check is required. I don't think you can get any cleaner than that...

Comment: It is a bit weird that there are votes to close because the question can generate too many answers.  I think the only answers could be "can't be done (use pointer or a copy (optional being a copy)" or use iterator, which is some kind of pointer and in fact is a bit worse because it contains information about the container which you want to hide.

Comment: @Nim I'm just trying to learn how to do this without pointers. It may not be good way or a better way, I'm just trying to learn how to do some things in C++..

Comment: @John the difference between a reference and a pointer is exactly only the possibility of "no value present"

Comment: @Caleth Well, in my case when "Other" is out of scope, all my objects are destroyed. But if I use "new", then none of the objects are destroyed unless I use "delete" in the destructor...

Comment: @Caleth: Not really. A pointer is an object by itself, a reference is just a way to name another object. `int* ptr` pointing to an `int` = two objects. `int& ref` naming an `int` = one object.

Comment: `bool getObjectForId(const int& objectId,Object& rep)` => this function prototype has *"premature optimisation caused by fear of copying objects"* written all over it. A coding style like this will cause endless pain to the caller because function calls cannot be chained and const-correctness is made impossible. Just make it `Object getObjectForId(int id)` and don't worry about the copies, unless there is a *semantic* reason to avoid copies, in which case `std::unique_ptr` may be appropriate.

Comment: @John you can use pointers without new and delete, with operator&. std:: containers guarantee that you can take pointers into them

Comment: @ChristianHackl what about `class T { U& member; }; sizeof(T);`? int* and int& are both types distinct from int

Comment: @Caleth: That's more like a side effect of the compiler's implementation, which may or may not be similar to pointers. Try `sizeof (T::member)` instead. Or try taking the address of a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning a non-owning pointer is perfectly reasonable and idiomatic.  Treating pointers as "references to data someone else owns that could not exist" is a reasonably pattern.

An alternative is [`boost::optional<T&>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html), but that is basically a pointer, and C++17 [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) last I checked did not support optional references.

[`std::experimental::observer_ptr<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr) is another option, or writing your own, if you want to be extremely clear that your `T*` is not-owning.  An `observer_ptr<T>` is basically a `boost::optional<T&>` I believe.

Answer (score 4):

I'd plump for `boost::optional` as it conforms to the *direction* in which idiomatic C++ code is heading.

It will be adopted into the C++ standard from C++17 onwards as `std::optional`. For more details, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional.

If you're reluctant to use the boost library or the timescales in migrating your toolchain to a C++17 standards compliant compiler are too long, then you could handcode the relevant functionality of `std::optional` in a few lines of code.

Comment: I probably haven't used `std::optional` enough, but how does that avoid making the copy?  I thought that it holds a copy and a mechanism to check that the copy is valid.  The linked page also states: "Thus, an optional object models an object, not a pointer"

Comment: I'm trying to learn how to do all these things without using any external frameworks... j

Comment: @stefaanv Where there is `Object&` you replace it with `optional<Object>&`

Comment: @Caleth: how does that not copy the result?  This only avoids having to return the 'succeeded' boolean.

Comment: @stefaanv oops, yes, it would have to be `optional<Object&>`, which is morally a pointer.

Comment: @John: It's not a *framework*. A framework is usually something that imposes an architecture on your software. Boost.Optional, in contrast, is a tiny library which contains a single tool which will become standard C++ very soon. And please take into account the second paragraph of this answer. You can write a simple version of `boost::optional` yourself in 10-20 lines of code.

Comment: C++17 does not have optional references last time I checked, just optional values.  Has this changed?

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Actually I'd really like to see a 10-20 lines of code implementation of `boost::optional`, I think it's more like 50-100 lines unless you'll cut alot of corners, like make it always default construct the value type and not actually use aligned storage properly.

Comment: @ChrisBeck: That's why I said "a simple version"! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ideas, to tackle the problem:

### Use pointers

You said you don't want to use pointers. But I find, that they are a perfect match here.

```
Object * Foo::getObjectForId( int id )
{
    const auto it = _objects.find( id );
    return it != _objects.end() ? &it->second : nullptr;
}
```

In fact, a pointer is pretty much an `std::optional<T&>`.

### Otherwise, use lambdas

Another way to treat the problem without unnecessary copies would be using lambdas.

```
template <typename F>
bool Foo::applyIfPresent( int id, F && f )
{
    const auto it = _objects.find( id );
    if ( it == _objects.end() )
        return false;
    f( it->second );
    return true;
}
```

You can use this function like this:

```
Foo myFoo;
myFoo.applyIfPresent( id, []( Object & obj )
{
    doSomethingWith( obj );
} );
```

This appears to be a more modern (functional) approach. It's harder to shoot yourself into the foot. However, it's also harder to read and it smells a bit like over-engineering. I would prefer the good ol' pointers.